# NOT IN FUNCTION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

I am having a problem with a sql query

Here is my query:

```
SELECT `rooms`.*  
FROM `rooms`  
WHERE (`rooms`.`room_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `reservations` `res` 
    WHERE ('2012-05-03' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date) 
    AND ('2012-05-08' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date)))
```

The problem is that when the second `select` returns null, it shows the following error:

`#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Can anybody help me?

`EDIT`

When I run this query it shows all the rows even the one which includes inside of the second `select`
I don't know why?

```
SELECT `rooms`.*, `type`.*, `status`.* FROM `rooms` INNER JOIN `room_types` AS `type` ON `type`.`room_type_id` = `rooms`.`room_type_id` AND `type`.`num_beds` >= 1 AND type.room_type_id=2 INNER JOIN `room_statuses` AS `status` ON `status`.`room_status_id` = `rooms`.`room_status_id` WHERE (`rooms`.`room_id` NOT IN (SELECT `res`.`room_id` FROM `reservations` `res` WHERE (res.expected_checkin_date >= '2012-05-01' AND res.expected_checkin_date < '2012-05-31') AND (res.expected_checkout_date >= '2012-05-31' AND res.expected_checkout_date < '2012-05-31')))
```

Comment: @Keyser Why do you keep perpetuating that myth? Last time I sent you about Sql Server that IN/NOT IN is performant than JOIN,  http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/ Here's for MySQL http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/

Comment: @MichaelBuen Missed your first comment. I kept perpetuating it because I read about it in several places. I now researched it thoroughly and now agree with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine you want something like

```
SELECT `reservations`.`room_id` FROM `reservations`
```

for the sub-select, since `room_id` is what you are matching on with the `NOT IN` operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT `rooms`.*  
FROM `rooms`  
WHERE (`rooms`.`room_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `reservations` `res` 
    WHERE ('2012-05-03' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date) 
    AND ('2012-05-08' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date)))
```

NOT in must be limited to the same list of values in the where so * won't work unless reservations only has a room_Id

```
SELECT `rooms`.*  
FROM `rooms`  
WHERE (`rooms`.`room_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT res.Room_ID 
    FROM `reservations` `res` 
    WHERE ('2012-05-03' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date) 
    AND ('2012-05-08' NOT BETWEEN res.expected_checkin_date 
    AND res.expected_checkout_date)))
```

Comment: Thanks, for help, it was because of this.